# Is it possible to use withInstance method to get an Sql instance with DataSource as parameter

Tags: groovy

In Groovy's `groovy.sql.Sql`, ans `Sql` instance can be instantiated with constructor with `javax.sql.DataSource` as input:

```
sql = new Sql(dataSource)
```

However, a drawback on it is that we have to *try-catch-close* to make the make the script execute safely.

`withInstance` can save the effort of using *try-catch-close*, but I found no overloaded `withInstance` method accepting `DataSource` as parameter

=>

**Question** : how to use `withInstance` in combination with `DataSource?`? or is it an anti-pattern to use `withInstance` with `DataSource` ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do:

```
new Sql(datasource).withCloseable { sql ->
   // use sql in here
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but in this case how to handle the exception?